# Colorbox - a jQuery lightbox - Width and height

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I am using the 'inline' method. I would like to reduce the height and increase the width of the lightbox due to the amount of content. How do I set the width/height manually in the code rather than automatic re-sizing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the properties of plugin:

width: Set a fixed total width. This includes borders and buttons. Example: "100%", "500px", or 500

height: Set a fixed total height. This includes borders and buttons. Example: "100%", "500px", or 500

```
var $form = $("#myForm");
$("#inline").colorbox({
   inline:true, 
   href:$form,
   width:"500px",
   height: "500px"
});
```